# как сделать чтоб при обновлении страницы сохранялись данные в стоках ввода

Tags: php

```
      <?php
    require "bd.php";

    $data = $_POST;
    if( isset($data['do_signup']) )
    {

        $errors = array();
        if( trim($data['login']) == '') 
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите логин!';
        }

        if( trim($data['email']) == '') 
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите Email!';
        }

        if ($data['password'] == '')    
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите пароль!';
        }

        if ( $data['password_2'] != $data['password'])  
        {
            $errors[] = 'Повторный пароль введен не верно!';
        }

        if ( R::count('users', "login = ?", array($data['login']))  > 0)    
        {
            $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином уже существует!';
        }

        if ( R::count('users', "email = ?", array($data['email']))  > 0)    
        {
            $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким Email уже существует!';
        }


        if( empty($errors) )
        {
            $user = R::dispense('users');
            $user->login = $data['login'];
            $user->email = $data['email'];
            $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULTs);
            R::store($user);
            echo '<div style="color: green;">Вы успешно зарегистрированы</div></hr>';

        }else
        {
        echo '<div style="color: red;">' .array_shift($errors).'</div></hr>';
        }


    }
 ?>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


 <form action="/signup.php" method="POST">

  <p>
    <p><strong>Ваш логин</strong>:</p>
    <input type="text" name="login" value="<?php echo @$data['
        login']; ?>">
  </p>

  <p>
      <p><strong>Ваш Email</strong>:</p>
      <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo @$data['
        email']; ?>">
  </p>

  <p>
      <p><strong>Ваш пароль</strong>:</p>
      <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo @$data['
        password']; ?>">
  </p>


  <p>
      <p><strong>Введите ваш пароль еще раз</strong>:</p>
      <input type="password" name="password_2" value="<?php echo @$data['
        password_2']; ?>">
  </p>

    <p>

        <button type="submit" name="do_signup">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </p>

 </form>
```

Comment: Ну можете хранить их в сессиях и просто выводить.

Comment: А что такое "стоки ввода" ? Первый раз слышу

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так, на примере одного поля:

```
 <p>
    <p><strong>Ваш логин</strong>:</p>
    <?php
        $login_value = '';
        if (isset($_POST['login']) AND !empty($_POST['login'])) {
            $login_value = $_POST['login'];
        }
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="login" value="<?php echo $login_value; ?>">
</p>
```

Или, в вашем случае вместо `$_POST` будет `$data`.